# ajax, plain javascript without jquery: where to put the text that will be sent as GET data to php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my HTML I have this line of code:

```
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" id="username" name="username" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="check" onclick="checkExistenceUsername()" /></td>
<td id="result_of_checking"></td>
```

How I tell to ajax that he has to take the content of the tag with id "username"?

This is javascript:

```
function checkExistenceUsername()
```

{
    var xmlhttp;

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("result_of_checking").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "check_existence.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value

Comment: Thanks I already knows that (DOM access...). I need to know where to place the code "document.getElementById("username").value" in the javascript code for ajax. (i have not been clear in the title, now i fixed it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

But instead of hard coded parameters you would need to add the input variable:

```
var params = "myvar="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('username').value);
```

Comment: I have to put the text in "xmlhttp.send(VARIABLE_WITH_TEXT_HERE);" ??

Comment: THANKS FIXED!! The key is this line of code and i decided to sent data with POST not anymore with GET.

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

http://coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-post-php